# Html.TextBoxFor with Format does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, html.textboxfor

For some reason the format of the code below is still displayed as dd/mm/yyyy.

```
    <div class="col-4">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BeginDatum, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { id = "BeginDatum", @class = "form-control float-left key", placeholder = "dd-mm-jjjj" })
    </div>
```

In the viewmodel:

```
    [Mandatory]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
    public string BeginDatum { get; set; }
```

We are using MVC v5.2.3.

It makes no difference

- in which browser the page is shown.
- when the DisplayFormatAttribute is removed.
- when the format is removed from the TextBoxFor.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Mandatory]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
public DateTime BeginDatum { get; set; }
```

Found the problem. The type was string and should be DateTime.